# PostgreSQL get all possible origin/destination node sequence

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, with-statement, o-d-matrix

I have this PostgreSQL table with node of a directed graph:

```
node_id | node_sequence 
-----------------------
   1           1
   2           2 
   3           3
```

I'd return a table with all the possible origin destination sequence (only in one direction) between the node:
(1,2); (1,2,3); (2,3). So the output table should be:

```
node_id
 ----
   1
   2
   1
   2
   3
   2
   3
```

Maybe WITH RECURSIVE is the right thing to do but I cannot understand how.

Comment: What are you defining as "combinations" of `a` ?

Comment: I edit the question. I'd get all possible value combinations

Comment: Why *not* {1,3} ? why *not* the sigletons {1}, {2}, {3} ?

Comment: It's a node graph table. I need all possible link and jump from 1 to 3 is not possible in my system. Sorry maybe my answer was not clear. I just edit it with pair of combination I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit from initial answer**:
You seem to have 2 constraints you do not mention in your question:

- You want sequences of at least 2 elements
- Elements in a sequence must be in ascending order and consecutive

Here is a simple query that does it (CTE GraphNode should be replaced with your table):

```
WITH RECURSIVE GraphPath AS (
SELECT G2.Node, ARRAY[G1.Node, G2.Node] AS GraphPath /* Start with 2 elements */
FROM GraphNode G1
JOIN GraphNode G2 ON G1.Node + 1 = G2.Node
UNION ALL
SELECT N.Node, P.GraphPath || N.Node
FROM GraphNode N
JOIN GraphPath P ON N.Node = 1 + P.Node 
), GraphNode AS (
SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[1,2,3]) AS Node
)
SELECT GraphPath
FROM GraphPath
ORDER BY GraphPath
```

Comment: It' doesn't work. I don't want the "{1,3}" combination

Comment: Can you detail the reason why {1,3} should be excluded? To me, it is a valid one (at least since you said "all possible combinations". Is it because 1 and 3 are not consecutive?

Comment: It's a node graph table. I need all possible link and jump from 1 to 3 is not possible in my system. Sorry maybe my answer is not clear. I just edit it with pair of combination I need

Comment: Unless you can provide with another table where the graph edges are stored, there is nothing I can do. There is no operator for things that are only in your brain.

Comment: Thanks it works. But it's not generalizable query because graph edge is specific for this example. I also have sequence of 100 nodes.

Comment: I replace with:  GraphEdge AS (
select * from
(select a.node as FromNode, b.node AS ToNode from GraphNode a
left join GraphNode b on b.node>a.node 
and b.node::int-a.node::int=1) as foo
where ToNode is not null
)

Comment: If the constraints was that values had to be consecutive, why did you not say so? You do not need edges for such a case, I am editing the answer for the easy case.